# Problem adding boundary condition using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Here is my code:

```
Vsimp[r_, ϕ_, z_] = 
  FullSimplify[(
   i ρ  (EllipticF[π - ϕ/2, -((
        4 a r)/((a - r)^2 + z^2))] + 
      EllipticF[ϕ/2, -((4 a r)/((a - r)^2 + z^2))]))/(
   4 π^2 Sqrt[(a - r)^2 + z^2])];

Vt[r_, ϕ_, z_] = 
  Vsimp[r, ϕ, z + h] + Vsimp[r, ϕ, z - h];

V2[r_, z_] = Vt[r, 0, z];

er = -D[V2[r, z], r];
ez = -D[V2[r, z], z];

Jr[r_, z_] = er/ρ;
Jz[r_, z_] = ez/ρ;

J[r_, z_] = Sqrt[Jr[r, z]^2 + Jz[r, z]^2];

i = 2000;
a = 300;
ρ = 100;
h = 2.7;
kt = 0.26;
kt2 = 2.6;
kt3 = 4;
α = 7.74 10^-7;

ro = 0.00001;
zo = 0.00001;
rf = 600;
zf = 600;
Tar = 18;
Tsolo = 18;
hc = 1;
tff = 9600 3600;

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

bmesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{ro, zo}, {rf, zf}], 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 5, "MeshOrder" -> 2, 
   MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximum", AccuracyGoal -> 5];

bmesh["Wireframe"]

eq = NDSolveValue[{D[T[t, r, z], r, r] + 1/r D[T[t, r, z], r] + 
     D[T[t, r, z], z, z] + (ρ ((J[r, z])^2) )/kt == 
    1/α D[T[t, r, z], t], T[0, r, z] == Tsolo, 
   T[t, r, zo] == T[t, r, zf] == T[t, ro, z] == T[t, rf, z] == Tsolo},
   T, {t, 0, tff}, {r, z} ∈ bmesh, Method -> "FiniteElement"]
```

I have to solve this simple equation:

```
Tzo = DSolve[{D[T1[t, r], r] + (hc/kt)T1[t, r] == (hc/kt)Tar}, T1[t, r], {t, r}]

(* {{T1[t, r] -> Tar + E^(-((hc r)/kt)) C[1][t]}}*)
```

but when I use boundary conditions to eliminate `C[1][t]`, `Dsolve` doesn't work:

```
Tzo = DSolve[{D[T1[t, r], r] + (hc/kt)T1[t, r] == (hc/kt)Tar, 
   T1[0, r] == T1[t, ro] == T1[t, rf] == Tar}, T1[t, r], {t, r}]
```

Instead it just repeats what I wrote. How can I solve this problem?

It's a convection boundary from a 2D heat conduction problem:

```
Ω = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{290, 0.001}, {310, 20}], 
   Disk[{300, 2.7}, 0.3]];

zxr = DensityPlot[eq[tff, r, z], {r, z} ∈ Ω, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Temperature around a rod buried 2.7m below the surface of soil(z=0)]

I want to change one of the boundary conditions I used to plot this. I used `T[t,r,zo]==Tar` but now I want a convection boundary, it is: 
`D[T[t, r,zo], r] + (hc/kt)T[t, r,zo] == (hc/kt)Tar`

Comment: Have you checked whether your `hc/kt` is `((h*c)/(k*t))`? Without `*` or space the fraction is of two symbols, `hc` and `kt`, rather than four symbols.

Comment: hc and kt are constants.

Comment: hc = 1 ; kt = 2.6

Comment: Tar is also a constant. Tar = 18

Comment: So basically the conditions `T1[0, r] == Tar` and `T1[0, rf] == Tar` are redundant? You can determine the constant `C[1][t]` with just `T1[t, ro] == Tar`.

Comment: It should be T1[t, rf] == Tar, not T1[0, rf] == Tar. Sorry.

Comment: Still, the condition `T1[t, _] == Tar`, regardless of `r`, is enough to determine that `C[1][t] = 0`.

Comment: No, it can't be.  ro = 0  and rf = 600. If r = 300 and t > 0,   T1 > Tar

Comment: How do you know from the solution `T1[t, r] -> Tar + E^(-((hc r)/kt)) C[1][t]` that `T1 > Tar` when `r = 300`? The condition `T1[t, ro] == Tar` tells us that `C[1][t]` is zero already, regardless of `r` and other boundary conditions.

Comment: I know from the boundary conditions I gave. `T1[t, ro] == T1[t, rf] == Tar`   If 0 < r < 600 T1 is not equal to Tar.

Comment: If `T1[t, ro] == T1[t, rf] == Tar`, then from `T1[t, r] -> Tar + E^(-((hc r)/kt)) C[1][t]` we have `C[1][t] -> 0`. Therefore, `T1[t, r] -> Tar`, i.e. `T1` is equal to `Tar` regardless of `r`. Tell me what's wrong.

Comment: No matter the boundary condition I use Mathematica only repeat what I wrote.

Comment: This produces a result: `DSolve[{D[T1[t, r], r] + (10/26) T1[t, r] == (10/26) Tar, T1[t, 0] == T1[t, 600] == Tar}, T1[t, r], {t, r}]`

Comment: Let me explain. It's part of a bigger problem. It's a convection boundary from a 2D heat conduction problem. I'll try to put some graphics here.

Comment: Or you can also tell us the equation you'd like to solve along with its boundary conditions in Latex form at the beginning of your question.

Comment: What's `eq[tff, r, z]`?

Comment: It's the result from NDSolveValue I used to calculate the temperatura `T[t,r,z]`, where t is the time, r is the horizontal distance from the rod and z is the vertical distance. tff is a constant, the final time.

Comment: Now `T` is a function of three variables? There're only two in the original question.

Comment: Yes, but T1 doesn't depend on z since it is T where z = 0.

Comment: I will put the whole code.

Comment: I guess you can't just use $z = z_0 = 0$ for the convection boundary.

Comment: Here is the entire problem.

Comment: After all, before going into the question of why `DSolve` doesn't work, have you actually realised by hand calculation that your boundary conditions `T1[0, r] == T1[t, ro] == T1[t, rf] == Tar` gives `C[1][t] -> 0` for the general solution `T1[t, r] -> Tar + E^(-((hc r)/kt)) C[1][t]`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematics one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: Thank you so much, Taiki. Now I understand what was going wrong.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how do I introduce the convection boundary in `eq`?

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen from

```
DSolve[
  D[T1[t, r], r] + (hc/kt) T1[t, r] == (hc/kt) Tar,
  T1[t, r],
  {t, r}
]
```

that this is not about PDEs as tagged. The differential equation is an ODE in terms of `r`. The following code

```
DSolve[
  {
    D[T1[t, r], r] + (hc/kt) T1[t, r] == (hc/kt) Tar, 
    T1[0, r] == T1[t, ro] == T1[t, rf] == Tar
  },
  T1[t, r],
  {t, r}
]
```

doesn't work because the whole thing is not a well-posed initial or boundary value problem. The ODE is of the first order in `r`, so you can specify **only one initial** condition **for `r` only**:

```
DSolve[
  {
    D[T1[t, r], r] + (hc/kt) T1[t, r] == (hc/kt) Tar, 
    T1[t, ro] == Tar
  },
  T1[t, r],
  {t, r}
]
```